# Apps Script Gadget not working on a custom website

Tags: google-apps-script

i  have this problem, and it seems that i'm not alone.

If i embed a simple apps script form with some textarea,buttons and labels in a custom web url    www.mydomain.com/mypage...the page simply don't show nothing and the Chrome console report that error:

Refused to display document because display forbidden by X-Frame-Options.

Instead if i see the page from the original url:

https://sites.google.com/a/mydomain.com/mysite/mypage

i see the apps script correctly.

Anyone solved that problem or can tell me a workaround??
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

This is a known issue and there has been a lot of chatter on this topic. Here is the issue filed in issue tracker. You may star it. People have listed some workaround as well.

[Google Apps Script Gadget not working with custom web address mapping](http://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=546)